# Java .jar doesn't work on other computer

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, jar, ide

I made a simple card game using Eclipse Kepler. I then exported it to a runnable .jar file.

When I double click the .jar file, **nothing** happens. So I made a .bat file:
`java -jar CardGame.jar`

When ***I*** run it, it works fine, but when my friend runs it on his computer (yes, both files in the same directory) the cmd.exe will tell him: `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

After some searching I read that I had to add `%JAVA_HOME%` in the .bat file. This made no difference for **me**, but it will still **not** run on my friend's computer.

So my questions are:
  - What is wrong with my .jar or .bat file?
  - Can I run it without the .bat file, if so how?

Comment: your path variable misses the java location.. so OS doesnt know, when you gave java as a executable command.!

Comment: How do I set it then?

Comment: _PATH="%PATH%":/usr/local/jdk1.6.0/bin_ something like this. Or better to get it added in the environmental variables.. as said [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: But isn't that different for every computer?

Comment: If he had java installed, the exact path needs to be mentioned.. other than that.. the concept is same.

Comment: We both use Windows, he 7, I use 8.

Comment: But on my computer I only have to type `java -jar CardGame.jar`. Not the whole path.

Comment: Take a look [DOCS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: This is all local changes, but how do I make a .jar that can run on any computer without having to tell everyone to do advanced stuff on their computer?

Comment: You can't if they don't have java, have multiple versions of java or store java somewhere that is not on the path.  On your machine, java is on your PATH so it works.  Java doesn't come as standard on windows: the JRE or JDK needs to be installed.

Comment: But it is installed on their computer?

Answer (score 0):

He needs to have Java installed in the default path.

The easiest way to get that is to go to http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp and follow instructions until Java is reported installed.

After that your friend should be able to run it.

Comment: I believe it is, does it have to be the exact same version as mine? Or does a 64-bit and 32-bit version difference matter?

Comment: With the error message your friend is seeing you need an approach similar to this to have your solution run.

Comment: An approach similiar to what? I'm sorry, I don't exactly know what you mean.

Comment: "The easiest way to get that is to go to http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp and follow instructions until Java is reported installed." - please try.

Comment: It is unable to verify on my computer.

Comment: I also have a jar created with netbeans. It runs on my machine, both from CMD and double-click but not on other computers even they have the same version of JDK i.e. 1.8 and build number 161 as well.

Comment: @iltafkhalid Open a new question.